# please help wrong password now locked

Tags: lumia, password

hello today my litle sister got my phone without asking and she typed my password wrong who knows how many time she did that and my phone is locked for 200 days. i searched how to fix that with hard reset but my phone need to charge and closed i plug the charger and now it wont open what to do. CRAZY SORRY FOR MY ENGLISH